# clang can't find an RcppMLPACK library

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have created an R package using `RcppMLPACK.package.skeleton()` function from [RcppMLPACK](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppMLPACK/index.html) package. When I try to install and load it using `devtools::load_all` I get the following error:

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '"/Users/vk6/Library/R/3.5/library/RcppMLPACK/lib/libRcppMLPACK.a"'

When I check the file, I can see that it exists:

```
bash$ ls /Users/vk6/Library/R/3.5/library/RcppMLPACK/lib/libRcppMLPACK.a
/Users/vk6/Library/R/3.5/library/RcppMLPACK/lib/libRcppMLPACK.a
```

My `Makevars` file in the `src` directory is the following:

```
PKG_LIBS= `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "RcppMLPACK:::LdFlags()"` $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: It is strange that it is surrounded with `'""'`

Comment: That's an older scheme of using static libraries we used with several packages.  You could, for now, also just write out the path in `src/Makevars` to see if it links.  Once that is working we can work out how to make the path computation right (if that is the problem).

Comment: Thanks, Dirk! Writing out the path explicitly in `src/Makevars` does link and compile with no errors. What would be your new way of computing the path without providing it explicitly?